# SQL - Union two tables and insert into third one if not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have three tables with same number of columns.

First Table **Offload**
Second Table **Offload_Temp**
Final Table **Merge_Test**

The data is periodically inserted into **Offload_Temp** (All the rows are deleted before inserting the new data)

```
delete from Offload_Temp
```

What I am trying to achieve is... Union/Merge **Offload** and **Offload_Temp** and insert into **Merge_Test**

The **Merge_Test** is already going to contain some data on it. I would like to avoid duplication.

The following is my query:

```
INSERT INTO Merge_Test SELECT * FROM Offload UNION SELECT * FROM Offload_Temp EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM Merge_Test)
```

Every time **Offload_Temp** is inserted with new data (It may contain same data) and the above query creates duplicates in **Merge_Test**

This process is repeated periodically.

How can the duplication in **Merge_Test** be avoided?

Comment: just to clarify on the query 2nd time. i don't find any duplicates. did i miss something?

Comment: Yes there are no duplicates on dummy data. Maybe I need to dump some more and try. 

What I am trying to achieve is... I have a main table Offload and secondary table Offload_Temp The data on the secondary table is going to be deleted and new data is going to be fed which may contain same rows as Offload I want to merge and insert the non duplicate values into Offload from Offload_Temp . Please advice.

Comment: and are you saying my answers did not work?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn It works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
INSERT INTO Merge_Test
 select * from (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM Offload
  UNION
  SELECT
    *
  FROM Offload_Temp

  ) x
  except
  SELECT
    *
  FROM Merge_Test
```

if offload and offload_temp can have the same data then try the query below. In saying that, UNION should give you distinct results. may be better to display your data for all tables.

```
INSERT INTO Merge_Test
     select * from (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM Offload
      except
      SELECT
        *
      FROM Offload_Temp

      ) x
      except
      SELECT
        *
      FROM Merge_Test
```

Comment: It is creating duplicates in **Merge_Test** table **Offload_Temp** may contain the data which is already present in **Merge_Test** and while running the query it is creating duplicates.

Comment: are you saying that offload and offload_temp can have same data?

Comment: Yes, they may contain same data. I want to avoid duplication. .

Comment: however UNION should give you the distinct rows... i wonder how does your contents looking like

Comment: if there is a column which will contain a different value with similar other field values then except won't work... therefore you have to use not exists

Comment: (0 row(s) affected)
The table **Merge_Temp** and **Offload_Temp** may contain same data or all three tables may contain same data. The objective is to avoid duplication.

Comment: the uniqueness of a column would fail an EXCEPT statement. @Tango  appreciate if you can attach your data

Comment: I have updated the main post and looks like the first query seems to work. What I am trying to achieve is... I have a main table **Offload** and secondary table **Offload_Temp** The data on the secondary table is going to be deleted and new data is going to be fed which may contain same rows as **Offload** I want to merge and insert the non duplicate values into **Offload** from **Offload_Temp** . Please advice.